# How to group types.SHUTTER like types.LIGHT

Tags: google-smart-home

I'm developing Smart Home actions for controling roller shutter devices through google home/assistant.
I have shutters in all rooms of my house, and can have several shutters in the same room. Individual control of each of my shutters works well.
But I'd like to request "close all the shutters of the kitchen", or "close all the shutters of all rooms" but Google does not recognize the intent.

Is there a way to group my devices (like the types.LIGHT) ? Or something else I can do ?
Thx,
Dam

Comment: This should work. I assume your shutters have the OpenClose trait?

Comment: Hello, yes I use the OpenClose trait, but doesn not work ... see the shot here ![pic]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zP9qUEVj9-H6TZO04YyuBYoqplzH8LC_

Comment: Grouping works well for LIGHT, but not for SHUTTER ... :-|

Answer (score 0):

Ok understood. Seems to be a problem with the french language :

"Hey Google, close the small shutter" --> OK

"Ok Google, close the big shutter" --> OK

"Ok Google, open the shutters" --> OK

"Ok Google, ferme le petit volet" --> OK

"Ok Google, ferme le grand volet" --> OK

"Ok Google, ouvre les volets" --> KO "Je n'arrive pas à déterminer l'appareil les volets que vous voulez controler" (translate = unable to determine which device you want to control)

What can I do ?